# MySQL NPM - Query to AWS RDS returns PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT after 1st call

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Using mysql to query my aws rds database. After deploying my web application when I hit the endpoint which is supposed to query mysql database, the 1st request is good but as from the second request I get a PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT error. Using the below code.

```
exports.scour = (req, result) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            sql.query("SELECT * FROM plans",  function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    result.status(404).send({
                        error_status: "INVALID REQUEST",
                        error_type: "Bad Request",
                        error_message: err
                    });
                    sql.end();
                }
                    result.status(200).send({
                        status: "SUCCESS",
                        total_items: res.length,
                        contents: res
                    });
                    sql.end();
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return result.status(404).send({
                error_status: "UNCATERED ERROR",
                error_type: "Server Error",
                error_message: error
            });
        }
    })();
}
```

I have tried using several placements for the `sql.end()` but none of them work.

Below are the codes I have tried without success:

1.

```
try {
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM plans",  function (err, res) {
       if (err) {
           result.status(404).send({
              error_status: "INVALID REQUEST",
              error_type: "Bad Request",
              error_message: err
           });                     
       }
           result.status(200).send({
              status: "SUCCESS",
              total_items: res.length,
              contents: res
           });
    });
    sql.end();
}
```

2. 

```
try {
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM plans",  function (err, res) {
       sql.end();
       if (err) {
          result.status(404).send({
             error_status: "INVALID REQUEST",
             error_type: "Bad Request",
             error_message: err
          });                     
       }
          result.status(200).send({
             status: "SUCCESS",
             total_items: res.length,
             contents: res
          });
     });
}
```

If I don't use `sql.end()` then the connection stays open which is not appropriate.

Comment: Quick note about http status: 404 is `Not Found`, `Bad Request` is 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How and where do you define your sql variable ?

You probably open the connection when you launch the server but you close it after the first call.

2 way to solve that

1. Assert to open the connection at the beginning your call, and close it at the end
2. Use a Connection Pool that'll keep the connection open with the DB and reuse this connection for many calls, offering better performances